# Displaying at different times

Tags: ipad

I have a split view app that displays a thumbnail image and a button for continuing to the full view. The label, right now, is just there to make sure that the button works because I have yet to connect the full view. When the app first opens, the image is not displayed since the user has not selected an image at that point, but the button (and label) are displayed anyway. How can I get the button and label to be displayed only once a user has selected which image to view from the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change default settings in Interface Builder for the button to start out as hidden, and also make sure that it starts out disabled so that users don't accidentally click it without knowing that its there, then add the following code to where you detect whether or not the image has been selected.

```
yourButton.enabled = YES;
yourButton.hidden = NO;
```

Let me know how that works out for you!

-Karoly